# Ubuntu 18.04 - fail to install using `apt-get install` after fail installing `VirtualBox`

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I tried to install `apt-get install virtualbox`. it fails due to dependencies issues.

to fix it - i tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and get stucked after a while.

now when I'm trying to install other ( git ), it goes back to same problem:

```
guy@desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for guy: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
guy@desktop:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.2.10
Kernel:  4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.2.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

Comment: I also have this problem, which started after the latest update. How did you solve it?

Comment: @lonix did you try ?

Comment: yep thanks I managed to fix it by installing the one from the Oracle site instead (5.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encountered same problem with VirtualBox v5.2

Try:

`sudo dpkg -r virtualbox`

or

`sudo dpkg -P virtualbox`

if it still asks - use `sudo dpkg --configure -a`